# Forming gerunds when an auxiliary verb is required

Tags: verb-agreement, gerunds

Earlier today I started to wonder if parkour could be used as a verb or should be in a gerund phrase (doing parkour).

parkour, from [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/parkour): "The activity or sport of moving rapidly through an area, typically in an urban environment, negotiating obstacles by running, jumping, and climbing."

The sentence I was trying to create was "He [was doing parkour/parkoured]   (something doesn't seem right about this) over a vacant, weathered plinth."

Which lead me to ask, how do you form gerunds with nouns requiring auxiliary verbs(to do + noun) or is this the present progressive aspect of 'to do' and not a gerund at all?

I am completely lost, and don't exactly know how to create a succinct inquiry for google. Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 'He was free running' is safer, until 'parkour' is verbed (accepted by major dictionaries as a verb) (it doubtless will be).

Comment: The gerund form would be [**Parkouring** Is The Bacon Of Hobbies](https://www.spreadshirt.com/parkouring+is+the+bacon+of+hobbies-A105426293), for example.

Comment: Ah, why didn't I think of that! Thank you @FumbleFingers. Much appreciated.

Comment: Does this mean we can now cite T-shirts on tricky English questions? :)

Comment: @ab2 - It beats reading it on the Internet.

Comment: Have I got it right that parkour can be used as a gerund? I have checked Oxford and Urban dictionaries to be sure that it is nor used as a verb, so is it possible to have a gerund form without having verb form?

Comment: @ab2: Over the years, Stack Exchange have sent me *three* ELU T-shirts (which I do occasionally wear) for being such a dedicated user. But I've never been accosted in the street by someone with a tricky English question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - All I ever got from *bicycles* was a lousy water bottle.

Comment: @Hot Licks: You mean from bike-shedding here on ELU? It's not like they send me *jerseys*. And my t-shirts are always white anyway (perhaps [Barrie England](http://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) got the *yellow* one this year! :)

Comment: I don't know how _do_ in _do parkour_ is considered an auxiliary verb.

Answer (score 1):

in my experience, these types of activities that are considered as a specific kind of sport/activity usually come with a verb that implies "doing/performing" something.
e.g. doing yoga, playing football, etc.

however, you also see examples like: meditating (performing meditation), wrestling, swimming, etc.

it seems the general rule of thumb is that if something would be easy enough to pronounce with an "ing" suffix (i.e, not too difficult to pronounce or ridiculous-sounding), then it gets popular as people tend to use it to save energy while speaking and keep things short. and when it gets too popular, the dictionaries have to accept it too.

Comment: Actually, there are general rules for these things. Sports played with balls are unmodified and used with the word "play."  Play soccer, play volleyball, play tennis, etc.  Most "leisure activities" are modified to use -ing and often are paired with "go."  Go running, go swimming, go camping.  Yoga is an exception because it's not from English. And we don't often add -ing to non-English words.  Hence do yoga, study karate, practice judo, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Those who practice parkour are traceurs, from the French word "tracers". I noticed with a search engine search that people are using the word "traceuring, which does sound better than using the word "parkour" in a gerund.

Comment: Edit- Oops, clearly I need to read better. :) I'm not sure this conveys the same nuance. Using the word traceuring leaves me to believe that we are emphasizing him as a 'traceur' rather than how he maneuvered over the plinth.

Comment: Traceur is the accepted word for the practitioner because the people who practice parkour are essentially tracing the obstacle course.

Answer (score 0):

FumbleFingers quoted a T-shirt [Parkouring is the Bacon of Hobbies](https://www.spreadshirt.com/parkouring+is+the+bacon+of+hobbies-A105426293) as an example (although not an authority) for parkouring as a word.

Against a T-shirt, the Oxford English Dictionary may be a laggard in sports vocabulary.  When I type parkouring into the OED, I get [No dictionary entries found for ‘parkouring’](http://www.oed.com/noresults?browseType=sortAlpha&noresults=true&page=1&pageSize=20&q=parkouring&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch), and an unhelpful list of what I might mean.

For parkour, the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/276444?redirectedFrom=parkour#eid) distinguishes between parkour and free running:

> Parkour and free running are frequently taken to be synonymous,
>   although in some usage the two are differentiated, with parkour
>   emphasizing the importance of efficiency and fluidity of movement,
>   while free running places more emphasis on acrobatic techniques.

The OED references its own entry on [free running](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/271446#eid209580485):

> 2009   Big Issue 19 Jan. 13/1   Parkour is a graceful gymnastic way of
>   travelling from A to B and involves vaulting or hurdling whatever
>   obstacles the urban environment might place in the way. Free-running
>   is its more freeform acrobatic cousin.

**Patience, I am getting to my answer**.

You are on the cutting edge of a sport.  Are you doing parkour or are you free running?  Do you agree with the OED's distinction?

If you think the OED is **not** up to date in its understanding of your sport, then go with the example of the T-shirt .  You are taking a part in changing language.  If you think the OED **is** up to date in its understanding of your sport, then don't use parkouring.  Or, if you are conservative in language, you might not want to use parkouring.  You might use [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10470/legal-situation-for-parkour-in-the-eu) on the Great Outdoor SE as a model, and say:

> He was practising parkour over a vacant, weathered plinth.

I, too, have difficulty seeing how a noun can become a gerund without pausing even briefly to become a verb, but I am not an authority.

Comment: I'm (pleasantly) surprised that OED has a 2009 reference; I thought it was usually 20-odd years behind. UD is, of course, often 10 years in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe KumaAra and Faradin are establishing the best answer. Let us allow that parkour is analogous to baseball: not a simple action, but a complex activity composed of a variety of simple actions, in varying sequences (and many more aspects besides). We would not say "he baseballed all over the field!" so neither would we say "she parkoured across the plinth." Also, you would not have "baseballers", but "baseball players" (notable exception outside of U.S.A.: "footballers").

So "play" is to "baseball" as some conventional companion verb is to "parkour". Perhaps:  performed, practiced, or employed? Or maybe "engaged in", "applied parkour techniques across", or "utilized"?